# Searching by text with Mechanize/Nogokiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape some data on average GPA and more from a lot of pages similar to this one:

http://www.ptcas.org/ptcas/public/Listing.aspx?seqn=3200&navid=10737426783

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.ptcas.org/ptcas/public/Listing.aspx?seqn=3200&navid=10737426783')
gpa_headers = page.xpath('//h3[contains(text(), "GPA")]')
pp gpa_headers
```

My issue is that `gpa_headers` is nil but there is at least one h3 element containing "GPA".

What could be causing this issue? I thought it may be that since the page has dynamic elements that Mechanize had some issue with that yet I can `puts page.body` and the output includes:

```
... <h3 style="text-align:center;">GPA REQUIREMENT</h3> ...
```

Which, by my understanding should be found with the xpath I used.

If there is a better approach to this I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a problem with the DOM structure of the site, as it contains a tag named `style` which isn't being closed and looks like this:

> ```
> <td colspan='7'><style='text-align:center;font-style:italic'>The
> institution has been granted Candidate for Accreditation status by the
> Commission on Accreditation in Physical Therapy Education (1111 North
> Fairfax Street, Alexandria, VA, 22314; phone: 703.706.3245; email: <a
> href='mailto:accreditation@apta.org'>accreditation@apta.org</a>).
> Candidacy is not an accreditation status nor does it assure eventual
> accreditation. Candidate for Accreditation is a pre-accreditation
> status of affiliation with the Commission on Accreditation in Physical
> Therapy Education that indicates the program is progressing toward
> accreditation.</td>
> ```

as you can see, the `td` tag closes but the inner `style` never did.

If you don't need this part of the code I would recommend removing this before trying to work with the entire `response`. I don't have experience with `ruby` but I would do something like:

- Get the raw body of the response.
- Replace the part that matches this regex `'(<style=\'.*)</td>'` with empty string, or close the tag yourself.
- Work with this new response body.

Now you would be able to work with xpath selectors.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have been the issue.

Comment: np, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

eLRuLL gives the source of the problem above. Here is an example of how I fixed the issue:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.ptcas.org/ptcas/public/Listing.aspx?seqn=3200&navid=10737426783')
mangled_text = page.body
fixed_text = mangled_text.sub(/<style=.+?<\/td>/, "</td>")
page = Nokogiri::HTML(fixed_text)
gpa_headers = page.xpath('//h3[contains(text(), "GPA")]')
pp gpa_headers
```

This will return the header that I was looking for above:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b28a8ec0c38 name="h3" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2b28a8ec0bc0 name="style" value="text-align:center;">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b28a8ec0774 "GPA REQUIREMENT">]>]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more reliable solution is to work with a HTML5 parser like nokogumbo:

```
require 'nokogumbo'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML5(page.body)
gpa_headers = doc.search('//h3[contains(text(), "GPA")]')
```